# How to record audio and video in safari browser in iOS devices and Mac OS devices?

Tags: ios, macos, video, safari, webrtc

Stuck with the implementation to Record Audio & Video in `safari` browsers.

What I have tried:

I tried using WebRTC to get access to the Microphone and Camera, I was able to show the permissions but I'm unable to get access to the devices. Below is my code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraintObj) {
                                let getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.getUserMedia;
```

I keep getting the below error messages:

```
getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser

Can't find variable: MediaRecorder
```

I was able to record a video from iPhone using the below code, but the same code doesn't work for audio.

```
<input id="recordUploadFile" style="visibility:hidden;" class="recordFile" type="file" accept="video/*" onChange='getFileNameWithExt(event, "record")' capture>
```

Unable to figure out below 2 cases:

- iOS devices - Audio Recording
- MacOS - Video and Audio Recording

Comment: I had the same problem trying to make a web view recordable for audio inputs. I had to add a javascript to the web view to make it available. I don't know if it can be your problem.

Comment: @Anirudh, Are you sure that the first snippet that you have is the full snippet used in your code? It seems incomplete..

Comment: Have you got any solutions?

Comment: @TheBeast apparently safari is going to enable MediaRecorder by default - https://webkit.org/blog/11353/mediarecorder-api/